# Telerik AJAX and updating a RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, radgrid

I have an ASP.NET page that displays a RadGrid with data. It displays a list of "groups" that members belong to. It shows the group name, and also an Edit and a Delete button. (There is also a seperate Add button on the page). Pretty standard stuff.

When you click a button to edit a group, we launch a new form in a RadWindow. This is a seperate ASPX page that shows up in the RadWindow. You can edit the name of the group, and add/remove members.

When you close the window, your changes are persisted to the database, and then an AJAX call is initiated via JavaScript. All it really does is re-set the DataSource of the grid (so we pickup the changes that we just saved to the database) and also calls a Grid.ReBind().

The problem I'm having is that, while everything appears to be executing, the changes don't appear on the grid until you refresh the page. This is because (I believe) that even though we changed the Grid DataSource, no postback occurs, and so, nothing new is displayed.

I was able to "fix" this by calling a little JavaScript magic to force a page refresh, and this works, however the entire page refreshes, and that looks ugly.

I tried adding the RadWindow to the AjaxManagerProxy like this, in hopes that it would AJAXify the grid refresh, but that's doesn't do it.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadProxy1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadWindowManager1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="GridGroups" />                                    
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
```

SO... the question is, how do I force the grid to refresh in an AJAX way? Without forcing an entire page refresh?

Comment: Are you making the edits in the RadWindow and then expecting the changes to be shown when you save and close the RadWindow?

Answer (score 4):

Todd, isn't [this live demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid) do exactly what you are asking for using ajax request on popup close? Take a look and let me know.